# Select a group of records that are the last one to their own type

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table

LogCheque (LogChequeID, ChequeID, Date, HolderID)

each row shows which Cheque (ChequeID) is transfered to Whom (HolderID) at which Date.
I want to select the list of LogCheques but with each cheque appearing only once, showing the last transfer

example data

```
LogChequeID     ChequeID    Date            HolderID  
1               1012        2013-01-10      200  
2               1526        2013-01-12      125  
3               1012        2013-01-19      413  
4               1526        2013-02-11      912  
5               1526        2013-02-17      800
```

and my desired output would be

```
LogChequeID     ChequeID    Date            HolderID  
3               1012        2013-01-19      413
5               1526        2013-02-17      800
```

I have tried

```
select lch.ChequeID, lch.DateFa, lch.ChequeID
from LCheque lch
group by lch.ChequeID, lch.DateFa, lch.LChequeID
having lch.LChequeID = (select MAX(LChequeID) where ChequeID = lch.ChequeID)
```

but it returns every row.

Any help would be greatly helpful and appreciated with open arms :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select lch.ChequeID,max(lch.Date),lch.HolderID  
  from LCheque lch
  group by lch.ChequeID,lch.HolderID
```

Comment: @Mahdi Tahsildari this very interesting?!? This answer wrong. Eror: Column 'dbo.test20.HolderID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CTE + [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ChequeID ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rn
  FROM dbo.LCheque 
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d8b2/1)

**OR** option with [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.LCheque t
WHERE EXISTS(
             SELECT 1
             FROM dbo.LCheque t2
             WHERE t.ChequeID = t2.ChequeID
             HAVING MAX(t2.[Date]) = t.[Date]
             )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b73c/1)

**OR** option with [APPLY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.LCheque t CROSS APPLY (
                                SELECT 1 
                                FROM dbo.LCheque t2
                                WHERE t.ChequeID = t2.ChequeID
                                HAVING MAX(t2.[Date]) = t.[Date]
                                ) o (IsMatch)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d8b2/19)

Answer (score 1):

CTE is much neater (perhaps more efficient) but you almost had it.

```
select lch.ChequeID, lch.DateFa, lch.ChequeID
from LCheque lch
where lch.LChequeID = (select MAX(LChequeID) where ChequeID = lch.ChequeID)
```